# Strange behavior of `BoundaryMeshRegion`

Tags: graphics3d, bugs, regions

`BoundaryMeshRegion` is new function of version 10. I am not familiar with the function. I want to decide whether a point is inside or outside in the Boundary using `RegionMember`. This code is not able to work. why is it?

```
BoundaryMeshRegion[{{4, 4, 4}, {4, 4, 6}, {4, 6, 4}, {4, 6, 6}, {6, 4,
    4}, {6, 4, 6}, {6, 6, 4}, {6, 6, 6}}, 
 Polygon[{{2, 3, 1}, {6, 8, 7}, {2, 5, 6}, {1, 7, 5}, {4, 7, 8}, {2, 
    6, 4}, {2, 3, 4}, {6, 5, 7}, {1, 2, 5}, {1, 3, 7}, {3, 4, 7}, {8, 
    4, 6}}]]
```

> BoundaryMeshRegion[{{4, 4, 4}, {4, 4, 6}, {4, 6, 4}, {4, 6, 6}, {6, 4,
>       4}, {6, 4, 6}, {6, 6, 4}, {6, 6, 6}}, 
>    Polygon[{{2, 3, 1}, {6, 8, 7}, {2, 5, 6}, {1, 7, 5}, {4, 7, 8}, {2, 
>       6, 4}, {2, 3, 4}, {6, 5, 7}, {1, 2, 5}, {1, 3, 7}, {3, 4, 7}, {8, 
>       4, 6}}]]

But this is able to work. What is different.

```
BoundaryMeshRegion[{{4, 4, 4}, {4, 4, 6}, {4, 6, 4}, {4, 6, 6}, {6, 4,
    4}, {6, 4, 6}, {6, 6, 4}, {6, 6, 6}}, 
 Polygon[{(*{2,3,1},{6,8,
   7},*){2, 5, 6}, {1, 7, 5}, {4, 7, 8}, {2, 6, 4}, {2, 3, 4}, {6, 5, 
    7}, {1, 2, 5}, {1, 3, 7}, {3, 4, 7}, {8, 4, 6}}]]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

### Are these bugs too?

**Case 1**

```
Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], tmp, Opacity[1], Red, PointSize[0.05], 
  Point[{2, 0, 0}]}, Boxed -> False]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

```
tmp = RevolutionPlot3D[{2 + Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi},
  PlotPoints -> 2]; tmp = 
 GraphicsComplex[tmp[[1, 1]], tmp[[1, 2, 1, 1, 5, 1]]];
r1 = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics@tmp
```

> [image: Blockquote]

```
RegionQ[r1]
```

> True

```
RegionMember[r1, {2, 0, 0}]
```

> False

**Case 2**

```
BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[
 GraphicsComplex[{{4, 4, 4}, {4, 4, 6}, {4, 6, 4}, {4, 6, 6}, {6, 4, 
    4}, {6, 4, 6}, {6, 6, 4}, {6, 6, 6}}, 
  Polygon[{(*{2,3,1},{6,8,
    7},*){2, 5, 6}, {1, 7, 5}, {4, 7, 8}, {2, 6, 4}, {2, 3, 4}, {6, 5,
      7}, {1, 2, 5}, {1, 3, 7}, {3, 4, 7}, {8, 4, 6}}]]]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

Comment: I also think it a bug. An easy way to achieve the same result is with r = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Cuboid[{4, 4, 4}, {6, 6, 6}]]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a bug, I think, and I filed it as such: The second region should not evaluate to a `RegionQ` `BoundaryMeshRegion`. A `BoundaryMeshRegion` is valid if it contains a closed surface. The subtle point about `BoundaryMeshRegion` is that this closed surface is a (sparse) representation of the entire region the surface encloses. Why the first one does not work, I must admit, I do not know. At least it's not obvious to me.

You can use:

```
bmr = BoundaryMeshRegion[{{4, 4, 4}, {4, 4, 6}, {4, 6, 6}, {4, 6, 
     4}, {6, 4, 4}, {6, 4, 6}, {6, 6, 6}, {6, 6, 4}},
   Polygon[{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 6, 5}, {2, 3, 7, 6}, {3, 4, 8, 
      7}, {4, 1, 5, 8}, {5, 6, 7, 8}}]];
rmf = RegionMember[bmr]
```

To generate the `RegionMemberFunction`. I just perturbed the coordinates a bit. You could try to replace the quadrilaterals with triangles and see if that works.

Comment: Can you check the additional question "Are these bugs too?"

Comment: @JunhoLee, I think so.

Comment: thanks a lot. Region -s are still in the while.