# BoundaryMeshRegion::buncl error in V 10.1, that works ok in V 10.0.2

Tags: graphics3d, regions

This code works ok in V 10.0.2 (from a post I was looking at [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57679/strange-behavior-of-boundarymeshregion))

I noticed what seems to be a regression bug. This code works in version 10.0.2 on windows 7

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Clear[t]
tmp = RevolutionPlot3D[{2 + Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotPoints -> 2]; 
tmp = GraphicsComplex[tmp[[1, 1]], tmp[[1, 2, 1, 1, 5, 1]]];
r1 = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics@tmp
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But on V 10.1:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Clear[t]
tmp = RevolutionPlot3D[{2 + Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotPoints -> 2]; 
tmp = GraphicsComplex[tmp[[1, 1]], tmp[[1, 2, 1, 1, 5, 1]]];
r1 = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics@tmp
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Is this a new bug in 10.1? Windows 7, 64 bit

Answer (score 2):

This could indeed be a bug, but it is one with a simple workaround.  Just don't set the `PlotPoints` to such a low number.  In fact, I find that with any number smaller than 6 it will fail:

```
BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics@
   Cases[Normal@
     RevolutionPlot3D[{2 + Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
      PlotPoints -> #], _Polygon, Infinity] & /@ {5, 6}
```

[image]

Obviously you get a better region the more points you use.  Here are the results from using `PlotPoints->Automatic` on the left and `PlotPoints->40` on the right.

[image]

The real question is, what kind of test is being applied to the list of polygons to see whether the region is closed?  By inspection, the following certainly appears to be closed,

```
Cases[Normal@
   RevolutionPlot3D[{2 + Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
    PlotPoints -> 2], _Polygon, Infinity] // Graphics3D
```

[image]

The workaround above is valid for versions 10.1, 10.2, and 10.31